# IIS: How to serve a file without extension?

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-10

I am using `IIS 8` on `Windows 8.1`. I have an `XML` file an I need to have it accessed through *(servername)/(path)*

*(path)* is predefined by someone else and does not contain an extension. I tried the simple solution of removing the .xml file the file name, but `IIS returns HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found`

In the *"Physical Path"* returned with the error is the correct file path, which when I copy-paste to Run opens the correct file.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Would one solution be to serve the file under `(path)\index.html`?

Comment: It is strange that the highly voted answer was not accepted.

Answer (score 143):

Assuming (path) is a physical directory on your machine, create a new web.config file in that directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />
         </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

You are telling IIS that for this directory only, any file without an otherwise defined extension (in MIME types) should be considered an xml file. Other file types in the same path should still work.

If you have the Windows feature `IIS Management Scripts and Tools` installed, you can use PowerShell to create such a web.config file:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/.well-known'  -filter "system.webServer/staticContent" -name "." -value @{fileExtension='.';mimeType='text/xml'}
```

in this example `Default Web Site` is the name of the web site and `.well-known` is a directory under that site.

Comment: For me `fileExtension=".*"` didn't work, but `fileExtension="."` worked.

Comment: This answer helped me to setup iOS Universal link apple-app-site-association file to be properly served by my website. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @NikhilMathew what mime type did you use to server your apple-app-site-association file? The above works for me to see the file but I'm not sure what mime type apple is expecting. I know it is application/pkcs7-mime if your file is encrypted, but supposedly you don't need to do that anymore so I am not sure what type to use for my non-encrypted file.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that using application/json works :)

Comment: `fileExtension="."` is what worked for me as well.  h/t @RustyX

Comment: Great answer.  This didn't work on IIS5 (I'm working on migrating legacy apps and hit one!); but for that @RBT's solution worked (only using file extension `.`. instead of `.*`, as per other comments on here).

Comment: This answer helped me set up Let's Encrypt SSL on Godaddy Plesk Windows Shared Hosting.

Comment: This `<mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />` makes IIS on latest Windows server throw an error "This is not well-formed XML". It doesn't like the space in `xml" />`.

Comment: @MikeMakarov you have to be more specific on what is the "latest Windows server" you refer to (1709 or Server 2019?).

Comment: @LexLi Server 2016, 1607

Comment: For apple-app-site-association better use mimeType  "application/json" , according to https://gist.github.com/andrewrohn/774185e4e15ddcc14f0a1e3c66c943e3

Comment: Mime type should be "text/html" to avoid strict xml parsing errors

Comment: Thanks, web.config  solution worked for me, for apple-app-site-association file i used MIME type as "application/json"

Answer (score 19):

It can be done in IIS 6 as well / without using `web.config`, but instead using the management GUI to add a MIME type for extension `.` here:

[image]

For instance, to serve a `.well-known/acme-challenge` token, create a virtual directory called `.well-known`, and have it take its contents from a physical directory (that cannot have names with leading dots in windows). Then add a `text/plain` MIME type for the extension `.` in this directory, and you can manually acquire new `letsencrypt` certificates for a domain that is currently served by an old IIS.

Comment: you can have . in the start of a directory in windows just create a directory called `.well-known.` (explorer will remove the last dot and you will be left with `.well-known`)

Comment: The "Mime Types" section in IIS 7+ will allow you to do this as well.  Right click, add an extension `.` (just a dot) with the mime type `text/plain` (for acme-challenge) or `text/xml` (for xml).

Comment: thanks! this was my exact use case and need. you're a champ!

Answer (score 13):

Changing the configurations by hand can be error-prone. So Internet Information Server (IIS) console GUI provides an easier and error-free way to update the MIME-types. Please follow the steps below:

1. Open IIS
2. Expand your website's node in the left navigation pane.
3. Select your application or virtual directory.
4. Double-click **MIME Types** feature under **IIS** section in the right pane:

   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Add..</kbd> link in **Actions** pane. Set-up the mime type to support all files without extension. Then click <kbd>OK</kbd> :

   [image]

Behind the scene, these steps make changes to **web.config** file of your application or virtual directory (under your website) as suggested in [PeterHahndorf's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963548/465053).

**Note**: The screenshots shown in the steps above have been taken from Windows 10 machine having IIS v10.

Comment: Quoting RustyX: "For me fileExtension=".*" didn't work, but fileExtension="." worked."

Comment: ok. Given the number of upvotes on @RustyX's comment I'm sure this is the case which you've observed. One of intentions of my post was also to make the readers aware on how to achieve this change through IIS manager UI instead of playing with config files directly.

Comment: This is really counterintuitively! But, this is working!

Comment: IMO this is the safest way to do the change.  In our case IIS was being used to update agents, but wasn't working for Linux.  I added definitions for '.' and '.*' but got an 'internal server error' when I tried to download the file without the extension.  Turned out the Sophos update site had '.*' already defined as 'Sophos/updates', so I removed my definition.  All is well now: the addition of '.' definition was what fixed it ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I want only to serve one file
so what I did is just add a simple rewrite as the other methods posted here didn't work for some reasons

```
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="apple-app-site-association" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                  <match url="apple-app-site-association" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/apple-app-site-association.txt" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```