# using IIS to serve files without extension as plain text

Tags: iis, web-config, mime-types

I've tried using an answer from [IIS: How to serve a file without extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950882/iis-how-to-serve-a-file-without-extension)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="text/plain" />
         </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Which is letting me target the file, but not access it

> **HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found**
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS: How to serve a file without extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950882/iis-how-to-serve-a-file-without-extension)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/html" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: I think it would be worth adding which IIS this is for.  Maybe I have another conflicting config, but IIS is throwing up saying that I cannot have fileExtension="".  This is for 2008 R2, IIS 7.5