# a href download doesn't work with some extensions or with files without extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, frontend

a href download doesn't work with some extensions or with files without extensions.

Works fine:

```
<a href="/test.txt" download>test.txt</a>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<a href="/test" download>test</a>
<a href="/test.exe" download>test.exe</a>
```

Also doesn't work with: `download="fileName"`, `target="_blank"`

Is there way to force download files with other extensions?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for help, HTML5 works fine with any file extensions. I had problem with my web-server configuration (IIS doesn't allow download unregistered MIME types).

Solution described here:
[using IIS to serve files without extension as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908898/using-iis-to-serve-files-without-extension-as-plain-text/27910763)

Answer (score 1):

i will  recommend to add a direct link of dropbox or anyother media sharing site as it is secured by http and can be allowed to download through any browser.
 or use this syntax for HTML5

```
<a href="/test" download="test">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only in modern browsers that support HTML5 the following is possible:

```
<a href="/test" download>Download</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/test" download="test">Download</a>
```

If HTML5 is not supported :

```
<a href="/test.txt" download="test">Download</a>
```

With `_target`:

```
<a href="/test.txt" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

With the `download` attribute you can use it to change the name of the file actually being downloaded like this:

```
download="name of the file"
```

For `.exe` all you need to do is a simple anchor tag:

```
<a href="/test.exe">Download Executable</a>
```