# How to serve static file from Asp .Net Core with period in directory name

Tags: asp.net-core, applepay

I am currently trying to associate Apple Pay with a website. In order to verify the domain, Apple Pay requires that the website be able to serve a specific static file at `https://websiteurl/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`.

I am currently unable to get my website to serve this static file. I am able to serve other static files, just not this specific one. I suppose the problem has something to do with the period in the directory name. I have tried to follow suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878091/azure-websites-well-known-route-becomes-inaccessible) but without success.

My `wwwroot` directory structure looks like this:

```
wwwroot
    .well-known
        apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association
        web.config
    App_Data
    Content
    css
    js
        app.js
    lib
```

the contents of .well-known -> web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I believe this is what what described in the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878091/azure-websites-well-known-route-becomes-inaccessible).

However, when I attempt to access https://websiteurl/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association, I get an HTTP 404 error.

I verified that I can access static files successfully because https://websiteurl/js/app.js works successfully.

I also tried putting `web.config` directly under `wwwroot`

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: what if you give the file an extension, can it be downloaded with the extension?

Comment: No, Apple requires the directory and file names to be exactly what I posted in the question.

Comment: @Mike; Please mark the answer as an accepted (even yours) if it was helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not the period in the directory name, but rather the lack of extension on the file. The following code in Startup.cs solved the problem:

```
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions    
    {
         FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/.well-known")),
         RequestPath = "/.well-known",
         ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
         DefaultContentType = "text/plain"
     });
```

Comment: I believe it should be PhysicalFileProvider and not physicalFileProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Try FileServer :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/wwwroot",
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
    });
}
```