# IIS Web.config - Ensure Detection of Files with No File Extensions

Tags: iis, web-config, mime-types, file-extension

I'm trying to perform a verification process by posting a file onto my domain.  Then, from the company admin portal, I should be able to browse to that file and complete the verification process.  It fails because my site returns a 404 Error stating the resource doesn't exist, when it actually does.  How do I get my web.config to recognize a request for a file with no file extension?!

In my web.config, but this doesn't work:

```
`<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
                              .
                              . 
                              .`
```

@LexLi, answered this question!  Here's how I updated my web.config file (below).

```
`<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
                              .
                              . 
                              .`
```

Comment: I wrote about it a decade ago, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/06/05/iis-7-dot-tricks-part-i/

Comment: @LexLi, I want to give you credit for the answer!  Post your Answer!  Worked perfectly!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS: How to serve a file without extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950882/iis-how-to-serve-a-file-without-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

For files with no extension, you have to use `.` in the `mimeMap` tag as `fileExtension`.

When I wrote [the blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/06/05/iis-7-dot-tricks-part-i/) in 2009, I was working for Microsoft and my colleague reviewed the source code of IIS to confirm that. Sadly it was never made part of the official documentation, so even after 2009 there were tons of discussions on how to.